# Android tab emulator blurs images, pls suggest

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop for an android tab with the resolution of 1280x720. But when I place an image, say 1000x500, into the xml view it appears almost two times smaller. When I change its height and width from wrap_content to 1000px and 500px, it looks ok in xml, but when I launch it in the emulator, it gets very blurry, as if it would be at first scaled down and then expanded again.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you put the drawables for tablet in drawable-xlarge folder?

Comment: use this for your ref: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-menu.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the drawables for tablet in the drawable-xlarge folder  and the problem may dissapear.

Maybe your problems is that the most tablets have xlarge screens and mdpi screen density and you put the drawables in the hdpi folder.

For more info see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) page.

Comment: for drawable extra large its drawable-xhdpi.

Comment: Note that screen size is not the same with screen density so for tablet size screen one must use drawable-xlarge-mdpi and drawable-xlarge-hdpi to make sure both screen densities are assured for the tablet screen. And note that currently there are no x-hdpi tablet screens accordingly to http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using "dp" instead of pixels. Also place the drawable in the density specific folder. between ldpi and hdpi the size in pixels need to be twice for them to show up as of same size on the device.  For example a launcher icon on ldpi device is 36 x 36px while on hdpi it is 72 x 72 px

Use same ratio to create your image in higher resolution with larger size.